# Is there a way to add a box on top of a navbar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

My intro HTML/CSS course has asked us to place a box in the nav bar: It should have a generic box for a logo on the right side of the nav that has a black background color. It should be 80 pixels by 80 pixels and touch the right side of the nav.

However, I've been unable to find any way to place something on top of the navbar. I tried adding  div to the nav, but then the box was hidden under the navbar. Any tips?

HTML(I know this isn't the best way to create a navbar, but it's what was shown so far:

```css
nav {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 4px solid green;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.box1 {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 3px green;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <p class="p1">Home</p>
        <p class="p2">About</p>
        <p class="p3">Contact</p>
        <div class="box1"></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` on the box with `top` and `left`

```css
nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box1 {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px green;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p class="p1">Home</p>
  <p class="p2">About</p>
  <p class="p3">Contact</p>
  <div class="box1"></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
}

.box1 {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<nav>
  <p class="p1">Home</p>
  <p class="p2">About</p>
  <p class="p3">Contact</p>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Us `flex: 1;` on textbox to textbox move right